# python find digits with leading '_v'

Tags: python

Is there a better way of finding digits in a string which starts with '_v' which stands for version number? What I want is just '001'

```
filename = 'greatv02_v001_jam.mb'

parts = re.split('_v|\_',filename)
>>['greatv02', '001', 'jam.mb']

b = re.findall(r'\d+', filename)
>>['02', '001']
```

Is there a way to split a string with something along these lines?

```
parts = re.split('_v###_',filename)
```

or

```
parts = re.split('_v*_',filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [lookarounds](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

```
>>> filename = 'greatv02_v001_jam.mb'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=_v)\d+', filename)
['001']
>>> 

>>> filename = 'greatv02_v001_av456jam.mb'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=_v)\d+', filename)
['001']

>>> filename = 'greatv02_v001_v456jam.mb'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=_v)\d+', filename)
['001', '456']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but you could [partition](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) the file name twice

```
>>> filename.partition('_v')[2].partition('_')[0]
'001'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex's grouping like this:

```
.*_v(\d+).*
```

Demo:

```
>>> filename = 'greatv02_v001_jam.mb'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'.*_v(\d+).*')
>>> re.search(pattern, filename).group(1)
'001'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the regex `_v(?P<version>\d+).*`:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("_v(?P<version>\d+).*")
>>> r = regex.search(string)

# List the groups found
>>> r.groups()
(u'001',)

# List the named dictionary objects found
>>> r.groupdict()
{u'version': u'001'}

# Run findall
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'001']

# Run timeit test
>>> setup = ur"import re; regex =re.compile("_v(?P<version>\d+).*");string="""greatv02_v00 ...
>>> t = timeit.Timer('regex.search(string)',setup)
>>> t.timeit(10000)
0.005126953125
```